# Display item details after clicking on element

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am working on a project where we have a few items in the database that are displayed on a website and that works fine code is below:

```
<form method="post" action="store.php?action=add&ItemNo=<?php echo $products['ItemNo']; ?>">
    <a href="product.php"><div class="products">
        <img src="<?php echo $products['img'];?>" class="img-responsive"/>
        <!--  this connects to the database and gets the image of item    -->
        <h4><?php echo $products['ItemName'];?></h4>
        <h3>$ <?php echo $products['Price'];?></h3> 
        <input type="text" name="Quantity" class="form-control" value="1"/>
        <!--  This creates an box where the default qnt is set to 1    -->
        <input type="hidden" name="ItemName" value="<?php echo $products['ItemName']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Price" value="<?php echo $products['Price']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="addtocart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-info"
               value="Add to Cart"/>
        <!--   this creates the btn that adds item to cart   -->
        </div>
    </a>
</form>
```

Now I am trying to show more details about each product. All I want is when the user clicks any item they will be sent to `item.php` page where there will be more details about that specific item.

At this moment I got all info displaying in item.php and I am stuck.

I do not know how to word this question, maybe that is why I cannot find any help out on Google. I am new to PHP as I just started with it few weeks ago.

Comment: Do you have a page with a list and a page with a specific? You need a technique to combine this into one result. You can display a popup (I do not recommend), upload data to iframe (I also do not recommend it), send the entire form (without ordering option) with id, which display details (exceptionally I do not recommend it), immediately load data and show them by a few (e.g. `jQuery ('#id-product') show()`) (I do not recommend for a large list of results) or load data using AJAX (and even websocket). From the point of view of programming science, you should practice all methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly

```
<a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $products['ItemNo']; ?>">
```

then on product.php check the url for $_GET['id'] and use that in your query.

```
SELECT * from foo where id=$id
```

but dont use the raw id or a non parametrised query unless you like being hacked

Comment: @DawidGodawa Start by changing the way you connect to the PDO driver (and `prepare`), or use some library like `database query builder`

Comment: quite a few things are called "query builder" did you have a specific thing in mind? @bato3

Comment: I like the solution used in kohana, but I do not want to impose solutions on anyone. (Except using prepared queries) https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/database/query/builder

Comment: What I have in mind is when the user clicks on any item new page opens with item details such as echo $products['ItemName'] etc.

Comment: @DawidGodawa that's what i just answered? what in my answer is unclear?

Comment: neato, have fun :-)